# Fixed-width div with % width div?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to use a fixed width div and an expanding div? Something like:

```
<div style="float:left; width:200px">
</div>

<div style="float:left; width:100%"> // expand please
</div>

<div style="position:fixed; width:320px">
</div>
```

I'd like the middle div to just expand in width and take up whatever is left after position the left and right div. It works fine if I give each of them a width in %, but when using a fixed-width for some, they start overlapping when the browser frame gets small etc,

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fixed - Liquid - Fixed Layout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558761/fixed-liquid-fixed-layout)

Comment: See my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2357101/how-to-places-two-divs-in-one-row-one-fixed-other-is-stretched

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div style="float:left;width:200px;background:red">&nbsp;
    </div>

    <div style="float:right; width:320px;background:blue">&nbsp;
    </div>

    <div style="background:black">&nbsp;
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="left:0;width:30px;"></div>
<div style="left:30px;right:0;"></div>
```

You may need to make them absolute positioned and the parent relative.